# How do I execute a command in the foreground?

Tags: terminal, command

Can I execute a command in the foreground, by typing on the terminal the command?

e.g. `command &`

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 26):

If you drop the `&` the command will run in the foreground:

```
command
```

If you want to bring a background command to the foreground, run

```
fg
```

You can specify a “jobspec”, for example

```
fg %2
```

will bring job number 2 to the foreground (`jobs` will list the job table).

Answer (score 12):

The `&` tells it to run in the background. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The command with & brings it in background.
if you type a command without &, you can bring it in background with:

```
CTRL+Z
bg
```

If you want to go back to foreground, type

```
fg
```